# Exporting designs in apps as vector (XML/svg) file?

Tags: svg, vector, shapes

My ultimate goal is to export designs created in mobile apps as vector graphics. Say I have a list of points of corners of shapes and the respective color that goes inside each shape and this design is being displayed on a mobile app (iOS and Android because cocos2d-x is being used). Is it possible to convert this information into a vector file (SVG file which is essentially an XML file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG contains a `path` element that stores the lines that make up a shape's path. The `d` attribute stores a path string, and the `style` attribute stores the path's styling, such as stroke and fill. To export a shape to SVG there are several things you should care about:

- The size of the SVG in pixels (the `width` and `height` attributes).

Example:`<svg width='640px' height='640px'`

- The size of the shape in pixels (the `viewBox` attribute: left, right, width, height).

Example:`viewBox='0 0 100 100'`

- The color used to stroke the shape and the stroke width.

Example:`style='stroke:red;stroke-width:1px'` or `style='stroke:none;'`

- The color used to fill each shape.

Example:`style='fill:blue;'` or `style='fill:none;'`

- The shape of the path.

Example:`d='M10 10L20 20 L30 10Z'`

- Each path is [divided into commands](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData). The M command moves the pen,
  the L command draws to a new position, and the Z command closes the shape.

There can be any number of paths in a single SVG file.

Example SVG file:

```
<svg width='640px' height='640px' viewBox='0 0 100 100' 
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
     <path style='stroke:red;fill:none'  d='M10 10L20 20 L30 10Z'/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Okay, its starting to make sense. So if I had a collection of shapes with different colors, starting with the shape thats rendered the farthest back, I could write each shape's coordinates into an xml file thats being produced with the above structure, while alternating the fill attribute with the appropriate color?

Comment: Correct. You would use a different `path` element for each shape, and adjust the stroke and fill for each `path` accordingly.