# Generate picture using object implementation of the turtle graphics

Tags: python, image, svg, graphics, turtle-graphics

I am programming in Python and I am trying to create this image:

[image: img]

using object implementation of turtle graphics with SVG rendering. The image is a turtle hunt where several bluish turtles chase one red. I have started like this but I do not know how to continue.

```
class Turtle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 50
        self.heading = 0
        self.lines = []

    def left(self, angle):
        self.heading -= angle

    def right(self, angle):
        self.heading += angle

    def forward(self, d):
        nx = self.x + d * math.cos(self.heading * math.pi / 180)
        ny = self.y + d * math.sin(self.heading * math.pi / 180)
        self.lines.append((self.x, self.y, nx, ny))
        self.x, self.y = nx, ny
```

I would be really happy if there is someone who can help me with this issue.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear whether you're using Python's turtle library in an object-oriented fashion or implementing your own object-oriented turtle library.  If you're implementing your own turtle library, you'll need some other graphics library as an underpinning (e.g. tkinter).  And time and patience.

If you're using Python's turtle library, then defining a class called `Turtle` is probably a wrong first step as the turtle library already supplies a class named `Turtle`.  And I see little in your `Turtle` class that would be of use.  I was able to implement the following image using Python's turtle library in an object-oriented fashion in less than 35 lines of code:

[image]

Based on doing such, here are my suggestions:

- Pick a constant radius and using it along with `cos`, `sin` and `radians` from the Python math library, walk around a circle in 18 degree (360 / 20) steps depositing blue turtles (whose hue varies with the angle -- you'll need a phase correction.)  Skip the the two positions where the sine is effectively zero.
- At the 180 degree point, place a red turtle.
- Now we need to make the turtles move.  You can either use a `while True:` loop which you break out of in the end or you can use a more event-oriented approach with `screen.ontimer()`.  You can make your own list of turtles or use `screen.turtles()`.
- For each step of movement, move every turtle forward 1 pixel. For all the bluish turtles, you also want to repoint them at the red turtle.  To do so:

  `blue.setheading(blue.towards(red))`

  is your friend in any chase scenario.
- When the red turtle's X position exceeds the radius of your circle by some margin, you're finished.
- Add any necessary touchups to make it look better.

Exporting a turtle image as an SVG is a separate issue once you have your graphics working -- you should be able to find examples of such here on StackOverflow.

Comment: With respect to SVG export, I give useful information in an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097569/exporting-designs-in-apps-as-vector-xml-svg-file/36097659#36097659).